# Username/timestamp tables updated by XLOOKUP function

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet running a macro that username/timestamps any row that is changed in all of my tables. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lo As ListObject, irg As Range, drg As Range, urg As Range
    
    For Each lo In Me.ListObjects
        With lo.DataBodyRange
            Set irg = Intersect(.Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1), Target)
            If Not irg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, .Columns(.Columns.Count))
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = drg
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, drg)
                End If
                Set irg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
            End If
        End With
    Next lo
                        
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
                    
    Dim Stamp As String: Stamp = Now _
        & vbLf & Environ("USERNAME")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        urg.Value = Stamp
    Application.EnableEvents = True
                    
End Sub
```

The only table that is not currently updating is one that is updated using XLOOKUP function. When I try to run the above it returns "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". When I select Debug, the only line that is highlighted is "Set irg = Intersect(.Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1), Target)". Is there a way to have it username/timestamp the tables where XLOOKUP function is used to update the other cells in that table?

I tried to create new tables and transferring the data, pasted the data into cell then converted those cells into a table, updating the XLOOKUP formulas. None of these work.

Comment: A guess, but if you're looking for an event triggered by a formula like `XLOOKUP` recalculating, you need the `Worksheet.Calculate` event.

Comment: Just realize that Worksheet_calculate does not have a `ByVal Target As Range` condition.  You will need to keep a copy of the values somewhere and compare to those and replace those every time the sheet calcs.